# Is there an elegant way to do this in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want an algorithm to set the preferred name correctly. It will be the preference of the user. The user can choose between the social name and the civil name. Only one of those is mandatory, but if it's `nil`, I want to pick the other one.

```
if name_preference == SOCIAL_NAME_PREFERENCE && !social_name.nil? || name_preference == CIVIL_NAME_PREFERENCE && civil_name.nil?
  social_name
elsif name_preference == CIVIL_NAME_PREFERENCE && !civil_name.nil? || name_preference == SOCIAL_NAME_PREFERENCE && social_name.nil?
  civil_name
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way to emphasize the choice of the user.

```
if name_preference == CIVIL_NAME_PREFERENCE
  civil_name || social_name 
elsif name_preference == SOCIAL_NAME_PREFERENCE
  social_name || civil_name
end
```

The example uses the Ruby property that `nil` evaluates to `false`. Therefore the `nil?` check can replaced by `||`.

Comment: How is explicit `return`  relevant to the OP's question?

Comment: @sawa In which case is it wrong? The `return` part relates to elegant IMO.

Comment: When `social_name` or `civil_name` is `false`.

Comment: @sawa If both is nil it returns nil. I assumed that it is the implementation of a method display_name(). ;-) Got it with the return. Was in the first answer. I`ll remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Much easier to understand code:

```
if name_preference == CIVIL_NAME_PREFERENCE
   return civil_name.nil? ? social_name : civil_name
elsif name_preference == SOCIAL_NAME_PREFERENCE
   return social_name.nil? ? civil_name : social_name
end
```

I added the return statements for clarity though they are not needed.

Comment: It's really helpful! Thanks! :D

Comment: Even better `civil_name || social_name` and `social_name || civil_name`.

Answer (score 1):

```
case name_preference
when SOCIAL_NAME_PREFERENCE
 social_name.nil? ? civil_name : social_name
when CIVIL_NAME_PREFERENCE
 civil_name.nil? ? social_name : civil_name
end
```